# Python3 как получить координаты слоя div на экране

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется django 2.2, python3, как получить в переменную координаты определенного слоя div с определенным классом, что бы в дальнейшем сделать скриншот этой области.

Comment: Как вы себе это представляете? Вы в курсе, что ваш питон-код выполняется на стороне сервера, а отображение картинки происходит на стороне клиента. Это два разных компьютера.

Comment: @Xander Это я понимаю, мне интересно, можно ли как нибудь это реализовать... Например через куки...

Comment: Куки просто хранят данные, которые вы туда положили, и ничего более. А выполнение кода на клиентской стороне ограничено мерами безопасности браузера, и они уж точно не позволяют делать скриншоты. Потому что если бы любой сайт, на который вы заходите, мог бы делать скриншот вашего экрана, то это был бы полный ахтунг.